# Facebook graph venue search

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm currently using facebook graph API and I couldn't find the perfect answer for this question. Can I search for venues with a certain category (in my case nightlife) and in a location (can be coordinates with a radius) using facebook graph?

The only thing that I could find was the *search?q={query}&type=place&center={coordinates}&distance={certain_radius}*. As the query I added *Nightlife%20Club%20Bar*, but this returns me a reduced number of results.

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to search for a specific category, the query will only return Facebook Places with the specified words in the title/name. In other words, you can´t search for "all Bars near the location", you can only search for "all Places with *-Bars-* in the name".

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#search